# Hibernate-like framework for C++

Tags: c++, database, hibernate, caching

I am looking for database-caching framework for C++ providing the following:

- Generate object/table representations via some pseudo-language (macros/templates)
- Retrieve objects from DB by key when needed
- LRU caching
- Immediate and delayed update of DB on object update (via getter/setter methods)

Comment: http://www.cstech.com.tr/en/QHibernate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [LiteSQL](http://litesql.sourceforge.net/) and [Hiberlite](http://code.google.com/p/hiberlite/) and see if they can be of use to you.