# Open source ODBC connection wrapper C++ for MS SQL

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I am looking for an open-source ODBC connection wrapper for C++ to connect MS SQL 2005/8.  My application is running on windows but a cross-platform solution is preferred. The app uses stored-proc extensively.

Do you have any recommendation?

Thanks!
Gil.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this: [Hibernate-like framework for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304587/hibernate-like-framework-for-c)

and [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) as well.